# "No file found" keeps occurring while using $redirectRoute

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ngroute, route-provider

My objective is to have one of the links on my page redirect to another page on my website.

Here is one of the two links on my index.html page:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
       .
       .
       .
<body>
    <h1>My Home Page</h1>
        <div>
            <a href="login/google" class="button">Sign in with Google</a>
            <a href="login/facebook" class="button">Sign in with Facebook</a>
        </div>
<div ng-view></div>
<hr/>
```

- when the "Sign in with Facebook" link is clicked. It redirects to another page. I have this set up by using a 'routeProvider' which I have given below. Also this is inside a file called 'routes.js'. **Now the problem is when this is clicked, the page opens up but displays a 404 error. The console says that there is "No file found for: /login/facebook/"**

  ```
  'use strict';

  myApp.config("$routeProviders", function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider
      .when('login/google', {

      })
      .when("login/facebook", {
          templateUrl: '/partials/login/facebook_login.html',
          controller: 'FacebookLoginCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
  ```
- inside the facebook.html page that is in the '/partials/login' directory I have:

  ```
  <h1>{{name}}</h1>
  <button ng-click="FBLogin()">Facebook Login</button>
  ```
- and for the FacebookLoginCtrl in a file called sign_in_controllers.js:

  ```
  'use strict';

      myApp.controller('FacebookLoginCtrl', ["$scope", function($scope) {
      $scope.name = 'Login please';
  }]);
  ```

Also this is my app.js file:

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngRoute']);
```

I really don't understand why I am getting the no file found error when I actually do have a file that is located inside '/partials/login/'

Comment: can you recreate this issue within a jsfiddle or plunkr?

Comment: Yes still the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

By default angular routers use hash based paths within the app.

Unless you use html5mode and configure server you need to include the hash in link `href`

```
<a href="#/login/google" class="button">Sign in with Google</a>
<a href="#/login/facebook" class="button">Sign in with Facebook</a>
```